# Which products do NATO countries (read US) exclusively produce?

Tags: china, russian-federation, trade, nato, summary-request

Imagine Russia groups with China, Iran, North Korea, etc. They exchange currency to trade amongst themselves.

Would NATO countries still have something exclusively in their store that those countries don't have?

The subtle point is why not go against NATO (read US). Why they still can't? Not being rude here, I am having difficulty understanding why haven't there been two distinct groups yet. I am unsure if there has never been distinct groups, even during the cold war, that we know. Please give me a holistic yet concise summary.

I know the question contains two questions. It can't be separated because the essence will be lost.

Comment: The answer to this, and I swear I'm not being pedantic for it's own sake, is going to depend on how you define "product." Like, only the USA makes the F-22, but China and Russia both have 4th gen aircraft (the Su-27 comes to mind).

So the answer will depend heavily on how you envision 'products' to be conceived.

Comment: @William any produce. Whatever a country imports and exports. Dollars count too maybe.

Comment: What is the point in asking about NATO if you say "(read US)"?

Comment: @Azor The NATO is collectively the group, but the say of the US is the most important.

Comment: Major economic power on the Western bloc like Japan and South Korea are not NATO members, although strongly aligned with the US militarily.

Comment: @MSalters correct. Either way I would still put (read US) after that group. Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The single most important thing that NATO countries have (especially Europe and the United States) that Russia and China (less so NK) want isn't a product, per se - it's the opposite: staggeringly huge, cash-endowed consumer markets.

One of the reasons so many goods are imported from China to the United States is simple economics: the demand for these goods exists in the US.

Cutting themselves off from American markets would dramatically damage Chinese economic interests. Would they be okay? Sure. Would they be just as well off? Absolutely not.

[Russia is similarly situated](https://ustr.gov/countries-regions/europe-middle-east/russia-and-eurasia/russia) the U.S. massively net-imports from Russia - mostly oil. If Russia really wanted to isolate itself, the price it could fetch for its oil would drop - and oil is a major money maker for Russia.

The US would get stung in this as well, but by and large the tech sectors in NATO countries are healthier in many respects so NATO countries would be better positioned to switch to alternatives/adapt. Russia's economy [is largely dependent on oil exports](https://www.investopedia.com/ask/answers/030315/how-does-price-oil-affect-russias-economy.asp#:%7E:text=Oil%20and%20gas%20are%20responsible,economy%20was%20fast%20and%20devastating.) with roughly a third of it's GDP derived therefrom.

Cutting yourself off from your top customer is the sort of thing you don't embark on lightly.

North Korea, meanwhile, is basically doing just that. They're nearly entirely isolated from US markets and maintain an actively hostile stance towards the U.S. Their economy is also in shambles and aside from their nuclear program they are largely ignorable on the global stage.

The Warsaw Pact tried the whole 'make your own alternative to NATO' thing, and history says it doesn't end well.

Comment: It's a good answer. Especially the first paragraph.

Comment: "Would they [China] be okay? Sure." I find that dubious. China's already struggling economically on a number of fronts; I think that it's likely that if the US cut off all their trade with them, they'd promptly implode into such a damaging recession that it's entirely possible that the current regime would be overthrown (given that the legitimacy of the regime is based around improving economic and quality of life standards).

Comment: @nick012000 "okay" is also a matter of degrees. There's enough variables in play there that nobody can really predict what would happen. It would be dramatic though, you're right about that.  But it's not like China would cease to exist.

Comment: @WilliamWalkerIII "it's not like China would cease to exist" It might, if it implodes into a civil war with multiple factions striving to hold territory.

Comment: @nick012000 Yeah but... that's basically Chinese history repeating. They've a demonstrated resilience under those exact conditions. :P

Answer (score 1):

From a goods point of view, NATO countries offer civil aerospace products, and quite a few specialty scientific and industrial tools, in particular to do with leading edge chip fabrication. The latter are overwhelmingly deployed in East Asia, however.

Finally there are some exceptionally profitable sectors in western countries, like finance, real estate, health care, and telecom, which the Chinese élite would very much like a chance to invest in. However, this may not give western countries as much leverage as some observers think. On an aggregate basis, the total financial wealth in China is now reckoned at $120 trillion, competitive with continent sized groups, and leaves individual countries behind. The US does remain competitive on a per-capita basis, with $90 trillion in aggregate. This is according to [McKinsey](https://www.mckinsey.com/industries/financial-services/our-insights/the-rise-and-rise-of-the-global-balance-sheet-how-productively-are-we-using-our-wealth), with the $120T/$90T dollar figures are taken from [secondary sources](https://www.straitstimes.com/business/economy/global-wealth-surges-as-china-overtakes-us-to-grab-top-spot-mckinsey-report) referring the the same report -- the original is somewhat circumspect in the framing, presenting the numbers as ratios to GDP.

We should thus be cautious about using financial wealth as a measure actual wealth, and the report implies as much by using GDP ratios to avoid any such comparisons. The report also emphasizes that the majority of aggregate financial wealth increases in recent decades come in the form of real estate.

To answer the question of why not isolate, the answer is that trade is profitable for both sides.